# FancyBox not working in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, fancybox

I  have downloaded **fancybox-1.3.4**, I tried using it with one of my pages(which has a master page which has the same **DOCTYPE** as **index.html** of fancybox-1.3.4) I copy pasted the entire code(subtracting head, body etc) but it doesn't seem to work, however, if I copy paste the entire code(including doctypes etc. all) to a new **Default.aspx** without master page, it work perfectly.

please
Help me out here.

Comment: I don't think anyone will be able to "guess" what the problem with your page is without seeing the code. Can you provide a *minimal* working example that reproduces the problem? (Note the *minimal*... nobody here is interested in reading multiple pages of source code.)

Comment: You say you have copied the entire code excluding the `<head>` tag - have you remembered to include a reference to the Fancybox .js file in your MasterPage `<head>`?

Comment: `<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  !window.jQuery && document.write('<script src="jquery-1.4.3.min.js"><\/script>');
 </script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="./fancybox/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="./fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" media="screen" />`

Comment: @Heinzi There's too much code for me to paste, and minimal code would still make me add a lot of code, if you could download it and solve my problem, I'd be greatful.

Comment: @mudflap Is that href that begins with "./fancybox" going to the correct location?

Comment: @mudflap: Let me ask a different question that might get you started in the right direction: Compare the HTML source (as seen in the browser) of the Default.aspx (where it works) and the master-page-based ASPX (where it doesn't work). What are the differences?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the other posters; it's hard to know without seeing the code.  But master pages do change the client IDs on the page.  If you're calling the fancy box by ID, you might want to try it with a css class.

i.e.

```
$(".fancy").fancybox();
...
<a href="/SomeUrl" class="fancy" id="my_link">click here</a>
```

instead of:

```
$("#my_link").fancybox();
...
<a href="/SomeUrl" class="fancy" id="my_link">click here</a>
```